# What is the best way to interconnect a 5.1 home theatre system to a laptop and TV

Tags: laptop, audio, 5.1

I want to interconnect my laptop, 5.1 home theatre system and TV together so as a result I would just switch the input mode on the home theatre and it would play the appropriate input, preferably true 5.1.

[my home theatre](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/HT-AS1T/XEU), 
[my laptop](http://msi.com/product/nb/GE70_0NC.html)

I don't have a TV yet so I'd also like to know - how do I tell if a TV outputs 5.1?

Currectly I have my laptop connected to the home theatre through S/PDIF and during various 5.1 sound tests, the rear channels (and LFE) don't work alone. I used the 3,5mm to RCA connector as well but that way the laptop detected the theatre as headphones so that was even worse.

Comment: If I'm reading the [manual for the home theater system](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/EM/200706/20070604193320796/EN/main.html) correctly, that is the 5.1 decoder.  Its input is the normal stereo output of a device like a DVD player (and I assume a laptop).  The TV is an output device for the video signal.  If your TV has stereo output, it looks like that could feed the home theater input.  It appears to have inputs for multiple devices.